# Invalid JSON Schema Error

Tags: json, mule, jsonschema, raml

I am using Mule EE 3.5.2 and migrating to 3.6.2. I have a RAML Project with a json schema thats throwing an error mule invalid JSON schema error: value has incorrect type (found boolean, expected one of [array]). On further digging I found that the required attribute was the offending one as explained here https://github.com/mulesoft/raml-for-jax-rs/issues/81. But even after making the necessary changes I am still getting the same error. Again I am in Mule EE 3.6.2.
Below is the json schema. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Hari

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "http://example.com",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "record": {
      "id": "http://example.com/record",
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "id": "http://example.com/record/0",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "Account": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/Account",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "DeptID": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/DeptID",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "ProjectID": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/ProjectID",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "ProjectDescription": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/ProjectDescription",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Amount": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/Amount",
            "type": "number"
          },
          "CheckNo": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/CheckNo",
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "Reference": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/Reference",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "BudgetRef": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/BudgetRef",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Description": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/Description",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Oprid": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/Oprid",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Date": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/Date",
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "Account",
          "DeptID",
          "ProjectID",
          "ProjectDescription",
          "Amount",
          "CheckNo",
          "Reference",
          "BudgetRef",
          "Description",
          "Oprid",
          "Date"
        ]
      },
      "required": [
        "0"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "record"
  ]
}
```

Error log is as below

```
ERROR 2015-09-23 14:04:57,797 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
org.mule.module.apikit.exception.ApikitRuntimeException: Invalid API descriptor -- errors found: 1

invalid JSON schema (schemas/ip_revenue_management_input.json): 
error: value has incorrect type (found boolean, expected one of [array])
    level: "error"
    domain: "syntax"
    schema: {"loadingURI":"#","pointer":"/properties/record/items/properties/Account"}
    keyword: "required"
    found: "boolean"
    expected: ["array"]

error: value has incorrect type (found boolean, expected one of [array])
    level: "error"
    domain: "syntax"
    schema: {"loadingURI":"#","pointer":"/properties/record/items/properties/Amount"}
    keyword: "required"
    found: "boolean"
    expected: ["array"]

error: value has incorrect type (found boolean, expected one of [array])
    level: "error"
    domain: "syntax"
    schema: {"loadingURI":"#","pointer":"/properties/record/items/properties/BudgetRef"}
    keyword: "required"
    found: "boolean"
    expected: ["array"]

error: value has incorrect type (found boolean, expected one of [array])
    level: "error"
    domain: "syntax"
    schema: {"loadingURI":"#","pointer":"/properties/record/items/properties/CheckNo"}
    keyword: "required"
    found: "boolean"
    expected: ["array"]

error: value has incorrect type (found boolean, expected one of [array])
    level: "error"
    domain: "syntax"
    schema: {"loadingURI":"#","pointer":"/properties/record/items/properties/Date"}
    keyword: "required"
    found: "boolean"
    expected: ["array"]

error: value has incorrect type (found boolean, expected one of [array])
    level: "error"
    domain: "syntax"
    schema: {"loadingURI":"#","pointer":"/properties/record/items/properties/DeptID"}
    keyword: "required"
    found: "boolean"
    expected: ["array"]

error: value has incorrect type (found boolean, expected one of [array])
    level: "error"
    domain: "syntax"
    schema: {"loadingURI":"#","pointer":"/properties/record/items/properties/Description"}
    keyword: "required"
    found: "boolean"
    expected: ["array"]

error: value has incorrect type (found boolean, expected one of [array])
    level: "error"
    domain: "syntax"
    schema: {"loadingURI":"#","pointer":"/properties/record/items/properties/Oprid"}
    keyword: "required"
    found: "boolean"
    expected: ["array"]

error: value has incorrect type (found boolean, expected one of [array])
    level: "error"
    domain: "syntax"
    schema: {"loadingURI":"#","pointer":"/properties/record/items/properties/ProjectDescription"}
    keyword: "required"
    found: "boolean"
    expected: ["array"]

error: value has incorrect type (found boolean, expected one of [array])
    level: "error"
    domain: "syntax"
    schema: {"loadingURI":"#","pointer":"/properties/record/items/properties/ProjectID"}
    keyword: "required"
    found: "boolean"
    expected: ["array"]

error: value has incorrect type (found boolean, expected one of [array])
    level: "error"
    domain: "syntax"
    schema: {"loadingURI":"#","pointer":"/properties/record/items/properties/Reference"}
    keyword: "required"
    found: "boolean"
    expected: ["array"]
 --  file: schemas/ip_revenue_management_input.json

    at org.mule.module.apikit.AbstractConfiguration.validateRaml(AbstractConfiguration.java:199) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.apikit.AbstractConfiguration.initialise(AbstractConfiguration.java:97) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing the :

```
,
  "required": [
    "record"
  ]
```

So:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "http://example.com",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "record": {
      "id": "http://example.com/record",
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "id": "http://example.com/record/0",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "Account": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/Account",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "DeptID": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/DeptID",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "ProjectID": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/ProjectID",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "ProjectDescription": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/ProjectDescription",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Amount": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/Amount",
            "type": "number"
          },
          "CheckNo": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/CheckNo",
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "Reference": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/Reference",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "BudgetRef": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/BudgetRef",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Description": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/Description",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Oprid": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/Oprid",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Date": {
            "id": "http://example.com/record/0/Date",
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "Account",
          "DeptID",
          "ProjectID",
          "ProjectDescription",
          "Amount",
          "CheckNo",
          "Reference",
          "BudgetRef",
          "Description",
          "Oprid",
          "Date"
        ]
      }, "required": [
        "items"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have JSON with required field condition for array of array, instead required can be used only for array of records

So, Please remove 
,
  "required": [
    "record"
  ]

at the end

Comment: Please don't repeat the same answer that has been already posted .. try to post some alternate solution

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this solution, I got the same issue, I changed the **id** of the **properties** as below, it worked for me:
 `"ZIP": {
      "id": "/properties/ZIP",

      "type": "string"
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I also came across the same error message, but with a different schema file generated with an online schema generator.

The problem for me turned out to be that the schema generated was the wrong version (see [github issue](https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/raml-for-jax-rs/issues/81) that put me on the right track). So I had to change from:

`"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",`

to:

`"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",`

It seems like later versions are not supported and default back to draft-03 which produces a message about required and boolean (at least for me)

I know this does not solve the original posters questions, but I hope this helps someone else who stumbles across this question.

Answer (score -2):

Remove the   "required": [
    "record"
  ]
I have tested and works fine after removing it.

Comment: Please don't repeat the same answer that has been already posted .. try to post some alternate solution